# how can i bind my schema file using jaxb2-maven-plugin customized binding in the following way

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin

Below is a binding file which is successfully binding the element named NameList in the following schema file to the type List, but i want it to bind it to type List

how can i do so?

Binding File--

```
         <jxb:bindings node="//xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='BaseType']/xs:all/xs:element[@name='NameList']" >

        <jxb:property>
            <jxb:baseType name="java.util.List"/>
        </jxb:property>
```

Part of schema file-->

```
   <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element  name="NameList" type="tns:Names"/>
```

Corresponding java Code-->

```
   public class BaseType {

             @XmlElement   (
              name = "NameList",
              required = true,
              type = Names.class
)

     protected List namelist;
         }
```

Instead of the above code i want it to be

```
   public class BaseType {

         @XmlElement   (
          name = "NameList",
          required = true,
          type = Names.class
)

protected List<NameType> namelist;
     }
```